# Fast method to solve this Pascal's Triangle question

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am studying for TMSCA, a timed math test, and would like to solve the following question in under a minute. Is there any shortcut method? Any help would be appreciated.

The question:
Moving only to the right or upwards, how many paths are there from A to B?

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add components from left or below:

[image: [pascalwithgaps]

Answer: $145$

Comment: This is usually the first method taught to deal with such situations, and then binomial coefficients are introduced to try to generalize the result. When several segments are removed (without any apparent order to them) like in this example, this approach is often the best (most time efficient) way to deal with it.